# I'm using React and Electron to build an app on raspberry pi os lite and I want to display it using Xserver, but the results

Tags: reactjs, linux, electron, pi

```
[0] [2836:1215/135136.491786:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[0] [2836:1215/135136.491922:ERROR:env.cc(257)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

I need advice and help,  I just did it for the first time.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS Lite does not include a desktop.  There's no way to run a GUI app.  If you need a GUI, you'll need OS Full.

Comment: It means that I have to use Ubuntu and then make it boot .sh. Because I have to make it a GUI window for display.

Comment: Yep.  You chose the wrong OS if you need a GUI.